# Admin customer spam

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, admin, customer

**I removed customer spam from the database. But, the admin customer display still shows those customers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the customers from the database, you must reindex the `Customer Grid` indexer to remove them from the customer grid in the admin interface.

To do this, run the following command:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. That was what I needed...